# How do I save files edited with vim?

Tags: vim

I can't save changes after editing

```
sudo vi /etc/network/interfaces
```

Text before editing:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet ...
```

Edited to:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

What key combination or sequence must I press to save this?

Comment: If you are not comfortable with editing files in terminal based editors like `vi` or `vim`, I would recommend using graphical based editor like `gedit` to open them. Replace `sudo vi` with `gksu gedit`.

Comment: Or use `sudo nano` Its also command line but a lot more intuitive than vi.

Answer (score 130, accepted):

You're probably in editing/insert mode. You need to type the following sequence :

1. <kbd>Esc</kbd>, to quit edit mode and fallback to command mode ;
2. <kbd>:</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd>, start with a `:` (colon) then press `w` and finally `q` to **w**rite and **q**uit (or just `:w` to write without quitting)
3. then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to valid.

Comment: Sometimes got bugs- pressed **control** + **q**

Answer (score 18):

I usually press <kbd>ESC</kbd> and then hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and press <kbd>z</kbd> twice. Just like you would like to type two capital Z letters in word editor :) That saves your document and closes your editor.

Comment: Oh man, shift and double z, what was the design logic behind that I wonder, "what's the least intuitive command we can create?", ubuntu sometimes pisses me off like mad

Comment: @Sam, I just wanted to nitpick that vi has nothing in particular to do with ubuntu. Ubuntu was first released on 2004, while vi was created by Bill Joy around 1976, inspired by ed (dating back to 1971). This means that the shortcuts in vi predate those in almost any other still commonly used utility today. In a sort of coincidence, the first version of emacs, which has completely different weird shortcuts, was also released on 1976. Standardization efforts came much much later.

Comment: Wow thanks for the info @yoniLavi , my points is still the same though, so hopefully standardization efforts keep advancing.. :)

Comment: @Sam, vi keybindings are actually a lot more standard than you think; they're virtually ubiquitous.  Practically any program can be made to emulate vi keybindings.  Even the default Gmail keybindings are obviously (to a Vim user) based off of vi keybindings.

Comment: what about esc key does not work? Insert mode, just stopped.

Comment: @sephiroth do you know how to use the <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>z</kbd> commands to save file without closing it?

Answer (score 4):

Check whether you have administrative (root) privileges to edit the file. use this command

```
whoami
```

If the result is not "root", then you are not supposed to edit the file.

To login as root user, use the below command

```
sudo su
```

or

```
su
```

Edit the file,

```
vi /etc/network/interfeces
```

After the changes, save the file using

1. Press `Esc` to change the mode
2. `:x` to save and quit the file

Thats all

Answer (score 0):

this question was answered a long time ago, but in case it comes up in search engines again, this [link](https://vim.rtorr.com/) is a nice vim cheatsheet that you might want to bookmark if you use vim a lot.

By the way, You can use `:wq` to save and exit the file ( you should first press esc key to exit insert or replace mode and then press commands ) and  use `:q!` to exit without saving.