# VIM: save file without to close it?

Tags: vim

How is it possible to save the vim file without to close it? I do a change, save it immediately and continue to work with the file without to reopen it again...
I have found of course the question [how do I save files edited with vim](https://askubuntu.com/questions/252760/how-do-i-save-files-edited-with-vim), anyway the proposed solutions close the file after the job execution.

Comment: This is not a duplicate, because the question was to save file without to close it. The answers in the topic above save and close the file. How to save file and close it, I knew already early :wq!

Comment: It is now. I just updated the top answer there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should hit <kbd>Escape</kbd> and use the write command:

`:w`<kbd>Enter</kbd>

This will write the file to disk and keep the file open.

`:wq`<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Will write *and* quit the editor.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Could you please elaborate your answer and give more context why and how (eg: this won't work if he is in insertion-mode) he needs to type?

Comment: @MadMike Are you serious?

Comment: @fkraiem Could you please elaborate your answer and give more context as to why and how my seriousness is questionable... alright. I expanded the answer myself ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to press escape when you opened the file using vim and made changes, then type :w to save it without closing it

Answer (score 0):

if you want to save file in vim without exiting from vim, use this (to **w**rite):

```
:w
```

and if you want to save file and exit form vim editor, use this ( to **w**rite and **q**uit):

```
:wq
```