# Ubuntu terminal file

Tags: vim

I was not able to save the file. How do I save the file? I ran:

```
vim /etc/apache2/sites-available/laravel.example.com.conf
```

[image]

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8713/85695). Instead, paste the text directly into your question and use the [formatting tools](http://askubuntu.com/help/formatting).

Comment: @muru dunno if this is a permissions issue or a "how can I save a file in vim" issue. I don't see the relevant warning ("Changing readonly file") in the screenshot.

Comment: @t In that case:, consider http://askubuntu.com/questions/252760/how-do-i-save-files-edited-with-vim as well (about that warning: OP is in insert mode)

Comment: @muru I get the warning in insert mode as well. In fact, it's only in insert mode that I see it (I only get a `[readonly]` message before I enter insert mode). In any case though, since you'd VTCd on the `sudo` dupe, I've now closed it as a dupe of both.

Answer (score 1):

You can't edit `apache` configuration file without root privilege. Use `sudo` to run `vim`:

```
sudo vim /etc/apache2/sites-available/laravel.example.com.conf
```

Answer (score 1):

`vim` is a very powerful tool but not exactly easy to use. As a new user, I suggest you instead use `nano`. Alternatively, you can take the time to learn one of the great editors like `vim`, `emacs` etc. If you don't want to take the time to do so, however, stick to `nano` or `gedit`.

That said, in order to edit a file in `vim`, you first need to hit <kbd>iEsc</kbd> to leave the INSERT mode, then <kbd>:</kbd> to enter commands and <kbd>w</kbd><kbd>q</kbd> and then <kbd>Enter</kbd> (that's `:wq`). That will **w**rite the file and **q**uit the editor.

Of course, as pointed out by @SuB, you need to do all this (in whatever editor you choose) as root, so `sudo vim /path.to/file` or `sudo nano /path/to/file` etc.