# how to save terminal files that you opened with "$ sudo vi"

Tags: editor, vi

I am currently following a tutorial that asked to open a file with "sudo vi /..."
first and formost I have half an understanding of how to type but I managed and now I need to save the file but how do I do that? I tried to use ctrl x but that doesnt work and there is no other means in the file/ edit section of the terminal. Please help.

kind regards
coolxm

Comment: I'm no `vi` expert, but I think it's Press esc, then w (to write) and q (to quit) You should probably examine vi tutorials, such as [http://heather.cs.ucdavis.edu/~matloff/UnixAndC/Editors/ViIntro.html](http://heather.cs.ucdavis.edu/~matloff/UnixAndC/Editors/ViIntro.html)

Comment: Closely related: [How do I save files edited with vim?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/252760/how-do-i-save-files-edited-with-vim)

Comment: Why not use a more friendly editor instead, like `nano`?

Answer (score 2):

To save, press:

:w

That is, the 'colon' key, then the 'w' key. Then the enter key.

To save and quit, hold the shift key, and hit 'z' twice.

To quit without saving, hit:

:q!

Then the enter key.